# Is there a way to generate large primes in C#, without the use of an external library?

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa, primes, biginteger

I need to generate large prime numbers for a cryptography project. I noticed that .NET 4.0 has some built-in cryptographic primitive (for example RSA) which use random generated large primes (p,q for RSA). Do they all use a common built-in library which is public and can be accessed from outside their class scopes, or do I have to use an external library (I know there are simple algorithms for primality tests, I just don't want to implement more than i have to.).

Comment: @Corbin - not *all* prime numbers are odd (but large ones would be)

Comment: I misspoke I suppose.  But still, isn't 2 the only non-odd prime?

Comment: Yes, 2 is the only even prime.

Comment: 2 is the oddest prime ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET v4 (and later) Microsoft provides a new assembly, [`System.Numerics.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx), which includes a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type. However it does not provide any method to check for primes.

Mono (since before 1.0) also provides a `[BigInteger][3]` type located in it's `Mono.Security.dll` assembly. You can either use it *as is* or port the prime-checking methods (several methods exists) to the new Microsoft `BigInteger` type.

> Do they all use a common built-in library which is public and can be accessed from outside their class scopes

Yes, both `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and `DSACryptoServiceProvider` calls into CryptoAPI to do this. However CAPI does not expose it's own BigInteger code (even to native code) so it won't help you.

Answer (score 3):

Generate a large number in the range you require.  Test it to see if it is prime.  Reject and repeat if it isn't.

For the testing, just use trial division with primes up to, say, 1500 and then switch to Miller-Rabin.  With a properly implemented Miller-Rabin the chances of a hardware failure are greater than mistakenly flagging a composite as prime.